# MS Access 2007: Programatically add hyperlink to a form with VBA

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

A form populates and the OnLoad event tests for the value in a field. If that value is blank, then I want a hyperlink to appear in place of the textbox which I have figured out. The hyperlink needs to link to another form within the database which is my question.

Take the following snippit:

```
If cp = "" Then
    Forms[!MyForm]![MyTextControl] = "Update"
    Forms[!MyForm]![MyTextControl].IsHyperlink = True
    ' what is the code to add the link to the other form
Else
    Forms[!MyForm]![MyTextControl] = cp
End If
```

Any thoughts on how to create a hyperlink that links to another form?

Answer (score 0):

The text for a hyperlink in a textbox is:

```
="Form##form table1_form#This will open a form#"

="Display text#Address if required#sub address, eg form or report#screen tip#"
```

Comment: Thanks! Any way to add a filter to the form within this syntax?

Comment: I am not at all sure why you want to go about things in this completely non-standard way. If you really must, you will have to look at alternatives for everything. For example, you can check if formx is open and use the filter textbox on formx. Either formx or the textbox could be hidden.